# css grid unable to fill middle column 100% vh

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

I am prototyping a layout with css grid, where I have three grid areas named `discovery-list`, `drag-handle` and `sharing-list`. I need to adjust the layout according to the screen width/size. When the screen width is less than 500px, I want to stack these three areas vertically:

```
discovery-list
drag-handle (30px high)
sharing-list
```

If the screen is bigger than 500px wide, I want to place them horizontally:

```
discovery-list drag-handle sharing-list
```

The following image demonstrates what I wanted to achieve except the second one that does not work for me yet:

[image: vertical layout]

[image: horizontal layout]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="discovery-list">
    Discovery here
  </div>
  <div class="drag-handle">
    <div class="cancel">
      X
    </div>
    <div class="trash">
      xx
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Title here
    </div>
    <div class="share-button">
      Share
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sharing-list">
    sharing list
  </div>
</div>
```

**SASS code**

```
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: #20262e;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 30px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "discovery-list"
                       "drag-handle"
                       "sharing-list";
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 450px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 30px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "discovery-list drag-handle sharing-list";
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
  }

  .drag-handle {
    grid-template-columns: 100%; /* why it does not go vertically? */
    grid-template-rows: 30px 30px auto 30px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-areas: "cancel"
                         "trash"
                         "title"
                         "share-button";
  }
}

.discovery-list {
  grid-area: discovery-list;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: maroon;
  color: white;
}

.drag-handle {
  grid-area: drag-handle;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 80px 80px auto 80px;
  grid-template-rows: 30px;
  grid-template-areas: "cancel trash title share-button";
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-weight: bold;

  &.cancel {
    grid-area: cancel;
  }
  &.trash {
    grid-area: trash;
  }
  &.title {
    grid-area: title;
  }
  &.share-button {
    grid-area: share-button;
  }
}



.sharing-list {
  grid-area: sharing-list;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

My code is also in **this jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/w6jw0sLj/. thanks for help!

Comment: that's right @Michael_B

Comment: What exactly is it that does not work? On your lower attached picture, are you aiming to have the "X" as is but your are missing that background colour fills the complete middle area? When you clarify, I can update the below code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the attached code snippet. The solution is made by adding an extra grid that takes care of "drag-handle". That grid holds the 4 text-areas. By doing it like this, you can get the text-areas in "drag-handle" responsive.

```css
.discovery-list {
  grid-area: discovery-list;
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 125%;
}

.drag-handle {
  grid-area: drag-handle;
  background-color: grey;
}

.sharing-list {
  grid-area: sharing-list;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 125%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  1fr
  ;
  grid-template-rows:
  300px
  50px
  200px
  ;
  grid-template-areas:
  "discovery-list"
  "drag-handle"
  "sharing-list"
  ;
  }

  .drag-handle {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:
    1fr
    1fr
    1fr
    1fr
    ;
    grid-template-rows:
    50px
    ;
    grid-template-areas:
    "text-area-1 text-area-2 text-area-3 text-area-4"
    ;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:
    1fr
    1fr
    1fr
    ;
    grid-template-rows:
    300px
    ;
    grid-template-areas:
    "discovery-list drag-handle sharing-list"
    ;
  }

  .drag-handle {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:
    1fr
    ;
    grid-template-rows:
    50px
    50px
    50px
    50px
    ;
    grid-template-areas:
    "text-area-1"
    "text-area-2"
    "text-area-3"
    "text-area-4"
    ;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="discovery-list">Discovery here</div>

<div class="drag-handle">
  <div class="text-area-1">X</div>
  <div class="text-area-2">xx</div>
  <div class="text-area-3">Title here</div>
  <div class="text-area-4">Share</div>  
</div>

<div class="sharing-list">sharing list</div>

</div>

<script src="index.jsx">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `vh` instead of `%` lengths.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: #20262e;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;           /* NEW */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 30px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "discovery-list"
                       "drag-handle"
                       "sharing-list";
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
  /* height: 450px; REMOVE */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 30px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "discovery-list drag-handle sharing-list";
    grid-template-rows: 100vh; /* ADJUSTMENT */
  }
  
  .drag-handle {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr; /* why it does not go vertically? */
    grid-template-rows: 30px 30px auto 30px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-areas: "cancel"
                         "trash"
                         "title"
                         "share-button";
  }
}

.discovery-list {
  grid-area: discovery-list;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: maroon;
  color: white;
}

.drag-handle {
  grid-area: drag-handle;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 80px 80px auto 80px;
  grid-template-rows: 30px;
  grid-template-areas: "cancel trash title share-button";
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  
  &.cancel {
    grid-area: cancel;
  }
  &.trash {
    grid-area: trash;
  }
  &.title {
    grid-area: title;
  }
  &.share-button {
    grid-area: share-button;
  }
}



.sharing-list {
  grid-area: sharing-list;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="discovery-list">
    Discovery here
  </div>
  <div class="drag-handle">
    <div class="cancel">
      X
    </div>
    <div class="trash">
      xx
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Title here
    </div>
    <div class="share-button">
      Share
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sharing-list">
    sharing list
  </div>
</div>
```